# Unit test isolation: 20 lines of test for 1 line of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

As I understand, in unit testing [methods should be isolated from their dependencies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTestIsolation), so that they wouldn't be affected by environment changes.

Nevertheless, stubbing out all the dependencies makes me feel like I am testing implementation instead of behavior.

In other words, by isolating dependencies I am coupling my tests to the implementation details. Therefore, any [code refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) would cause failures of tests, even though behavior (the desired outcome) didn't change.

For instance, this is a simple (Ruby) method:

```
  def send_request
    update_attributes(response.page_params) if active?
  end
```

And these are my two isolated tests for this single line of code:

```
  let(:page) { Page.new }

  describe '#send_request' do
    context 'when a page is active' do
      it 'updates page with the response parameters' do
        page.active = true
        response = double('response')
        page_params = double('page_params')
        response.stub(:page_params).and_return(page_params)
        page.stub(:response).and_return(response)
        page.stub(:update_attributes).and_return(nil)
        page.should_receive(:update_attributes).with(page_params)
        page.send_request
      end
    end
    context 'when a page is inactive' do
      it 'does NOT send a request' do
        page.active = false
        page.should_not_receive(:response)
        page.send_request
      end
    end
  end
```

The tests are passing, but I see a few serious problems:

- If later I decide to use any other method than update_attributes() to persist changes into database, my tests will fail, even though the data will be saved as expected
- If the implementation of response.page_params changes, my software will fail in production, but the tests will still be passing

I must be doing something wrong.

What is the right way of writing unit tests?

Comment: I feel you. Unfortunately, there is no "right way of writing unit tests", just as there is no "silver bullet". In general though, yes, from experience you should be budgeting 2x to 3x more effort into writing proper unit tests to a good level of coverage and confidence compared to the code itself. On the other hand, my 'right hand rule' with code (and tests) has always been, "Am I getting more done with less effort?" If not, then there's an inefficiency somewhere that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are completely off mark here, as AlistairIsrael said.

There are a few optimisations you can do to make it more succinct. A good test should clearly show what you are expecting from your code.

```
let(:page) { Page.new }

describe '#send_request' do
  context 'when a page is active' do
    it 'updates page with the response parameters' do
      page.active = true
      response = double('response',
        :page_params => page_params = mock('page_params')
      )

      # not needed as .should_receive creates a nil stub by default.
      # page.stub(:update_attributes).and_return(nil)
      page.should_receive(:update_attributes).with(page_params)
      page.send_request
    end
  end
  context 'when a page is inactive' do
    it 'does NOT send a request' do
      page.active = false

      subject.should_not_receive(:update_attributes)
      page.send_request
    end
  end
end
```

From a few changes above you can see that rspec's double helper is very very powerful, you can construct complex objects and using some assignment stuff you can have access to the last evaluated method in a chain.

I made an assumption for the negative case, but you should get the idea. Testing for the method call of `update_attributes` is probably easier and is clearer as you know that `page_params` will never get called if the active? condition isn't met.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the great rSpec tips - they really made my tests shorter and nicer. However, I am still worried about how brittle my tests are.

Comment: If you're worried about tests being brittle then I would create real objects, and test the 'after effects' of what the methods do. This can be very tedious at times (recreating all the required instances etc) but makes your tests very robust.